# On get date + days, if a month exceeded, the month doesn't increase?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have 2 inputs and I am getting the date with Javascript. On the first input I want to add 14 days (2 weeks) and on the second 21 days (3 weeks). If the date passes the month, the month doesn't change.

For example:

If the date is 13th October 2011 and I add 21 days, it goes to 3rd of October 2011 instead of November.

How can I fix this?

This is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2CKyL/

Note that I'd like to format it as DD/MM/YY.

Comment: There are no alots to thank here. Except for perhaps James McNellis.

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you have some simple sample code you can share?

Comment: @Anirvan The code is already linked in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
var month2 = b.getMonth() + 1;

$(".input2").val(b.getDate() + "/" + month2 +"/" + b.getFullYear());
```

You were reusing `month` for `input2`, but month was the month of `a`.

To be clearer:

```
var a = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
var b = new Date(+new Date + 18144e5);

var month = a.getMonth() + 1;
// Here calc month2

$(".input1").val(a.getDate() + "/" + month +"/" + a.getFullYear());
$(".input2").val(b.getDate() + "/" + month +"/" + b.getFullYear());
```

**Two** dates (`a` and `b`), **Two** `month` variables!

Comment: Ah. I thought that would increase my date if it exceeded the month or not! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with modulo and a getLastDayOfMonth function:

```
Date.prototype.getLastDayOfMonth = function() {
    return new Date(new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth() + 1, 0)).getDate();
};

$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    var days = Math.random() + 100 | 0 + 30; // just a random number, nothing more
    a.setDate(a.getDate() + days % a.getLastDayOfMonth());
    $(".input1").val(a.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + a.getFullYear());
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2CKyL/1/)